# How do you use parseInt()?

Tags: javascript

I'm new on to Javascript and I'm having a hard time coding. I'm working on a project now which is a BMI calculator. The only step I can't get through is to "convert the value to an integer by using the parseInt() function." Where should I put the `parseInt()` function?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcBMI (form) {
        var h = form.height.value;
        var lbs = form.weight.value;
        parseInt(form.result.value);
        form.result.value = (lbs*lbs)/(h*h);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a way of using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (where `10` is radix):

```
var h = parseInt(form.height.value, 10),
    lbs = parseInt(form.weight.value, 10);
```

So the function *returns* the transformed value back.

**NB:** It is important to know, that for your case there is no real need in casting variables to integer, since multiplication `*` will automatically transform strings to number values.

Comment: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: it still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

> `parseInt(string, radix)`
>
> - `string`    - Required. The string to be parsed,
> - `radix` - Optional. A number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used

Taken from: [w3schools `parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Comment: Http://w3fools.com use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) instead

Answer (score 0):

Use Number() function instead.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

```js
function calcBMI (form) {
    var h = Number(form.height.value),
        lbs = Number(form.weight.value);

     form.result.value = ( lbs*lbs )/( h*h );
}
```

Comment: Using `Number()` as function is recommended way to convert string into number.

Comment: `parseInt("-15e1")` for example

Comment: Depends on the desired result. That could be accidental input from the user. If that notation is desired, then `parseFloat` would work too. I'm not saying that `Number` shouldn't be used. I'm just saying that there's no single recommended way. It depends on the situation.

Comment: yep, but if we want just convert number from string and don't need coercion between numeric systems, eg 16 -> 10, simplest way is to use `Number`. Also not all newbies notice that they should always specify `radix` to prevent unpredictable results :) Only this is reason - complexity for newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcBMI (form) {
        var h = parseInt(form.height.value),
            lbs = parseInt(form.weight.value);
        form.result.value = (lbs*lbs)/(h*h);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that most of the answers here are right. 
You are probably missing something else, in your JavaScript except for the parseInt.
Here is an example I built with your code (with a few minor changes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myform">
    Height: <input type="text" name="height" value="" /><br />
    Weight: <input type="text" name="weight" value="" /><br />
    Result: <input type="text" name="result" value="" /> <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="calcBMI()" value="Calculate" />
  </form>
  <script>
    function calcBMI () {
       var form = document.getElementById('myform');
       var h = parseInt(form.height.value, 10);
       var lbs = parseInt(form.weight.value, 10);
       //parseInt(form.result.value);
       form.result.value = (lbs*lbs)/(h*h);
 }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Try this code out.](http://jsbin.com/avetuv/3/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: the result is still in integers :(

Comment: I get it in point float, what do you type in the form?